Webpack compilation error with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
Error Message: Webpack Compilation Error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
Context:
I have installed cucumber package (npm install --save-dev cypress-cucumber-preprocessor)
I have updated my cypress/plugins/index.js file to configure Cypress to use the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
};

I have also modified my cypress.config.js file to specify the specPattern correctly for Cypress to find and run my .feature files.
{
  "baseUrl": "https://reqres.in/api",
  "e2e": {
    "specPattern": "**/*.feature"
  }
}

My code file directory cypress\integration\step_definitions\users_steps.js
import { Given, When, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';

Given('the API is available', () => {
  // Setup steps if needed
});

When('I request the first page of users', () => {
  cy.request('GET', '/users?page=1').as('getUsers');
});

When('I request user with ID 2', () => {
  cy.request('GET', '/users/2').as('getUser');
});

When('I submit a request to create a new user', () => {
  cy.request('POST', '/users', {
    name: 'John Doe',
    job: 'Software Developer'
  }).as('createUser');
});

Then('I should receive a 200 status code', () => {
  cy.get('@getUsers').its('status').should('eq', 200);
  cy.get('@getUser').its('status').should('eq', 200);
});

Then('I should receive a 201 status code', () => {
  cy.get('@createUser').its('status').should('eq', 201);
});

Then('the response should contain a list of users', () => {
  cy.get('@getUsers').its('body').should('have.property', 'data');
  cy.get('@getUsers').its('body.data').should('be.an', 'array');
});

Then('the response should contain the user\'s details', () => {
  cy.get('@getUser').its('body.data').should((user) => {
    expect(user).to.have.property('id', 2);
    expect(user).to.have.property('first_name');
    expect(user).to.have.property('last_name');
    expect(user).to.have.property('email');
  });
});

Then('the response should contain the user\'s ID', () => {
  cy.get('@createUser').its('body').should((user) => {
    expect(user).to.have.property('id');
    expect(user).to.have.property('createdAt');
  });
});

My feature file directory cypress\integration\features\users.feature
Feature: Users API

  Scenario: Retrieve first page of users
    Given the API is available
    When I request the first page of users
    Then I should receive a 200 status code
    And the response should contain a list of users

  Scenario: Retrieve a single user by ID
    Given the API is available
    When I request user with ID 2
    Then I should receive a 200 status code
    And the response should contain the user's details

  Scenario: Create a new user
    Given the API is available
    When I submit a request to create a new user
    Then I should receive a 201 status code
    And the response should contain the user's ID

Package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.12.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  }
}


The cucumber version is out of date and not compatible with the current version of Cypress.
The correct version to install is https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor@20.1.0.
The newer cucumber package requires one of the configurations shown here. If you don't know which one, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/examples
/webpack-cjs/ might be the best to try.
Also, since you have cypress/plugins/index.js it looks like you have already upgraded Cypress from an earlier version. The cypress.config.js looks like it's just cypress.json renamed, which will not work, but you can copy Badeball's example config from the repo mentioned above.

The issue was resolved, it seems in my cypress.config.js file, I was missing some code
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
   
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://reqres.in/api',
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/**/*.feature',
  },
});

All I did was update the above code as below and it worked.
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://reqres.in/api',
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/**/*.feature',
  },
});

and also add the below data set in my package.json
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefination": true,
    "step_definitions": "cypress/integration"
  }

